# Access master page from child iframe src page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp-classic

I have two pages "childpage" and "pageforIFrame". here childpage is the child of a master page "Master1". on the child page I have an IFRAME, its src is pageforIFrame. On the button click of pageforIFrame button i want the label inside the master page. Is it possible?

[image]

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the parent page from the iframe like this.
considering your myLabel has id="myLabel" place this code in your iframe script tag for click of button

```
alert(top.document.getElementById('myLabel'));
```

and chagne the label

```
top.document.getElementById('myLabel').innerHTML = "Hello";
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a javascript function inside that of the master page?

Comment: Yes it is, if those functions are global

Comment: cn u tell me how to call the global functions/

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible?

Yes, if the two applications are hosted on the same domain. You could access the parent DOM from the iframe like this:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById...
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a javascript function inside that of the master page?

Answer (score 1):

```
try to write this
$("#IfrmaeID").contents().find("#ElementID")
alert this and if this give object you can assign any value.
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a javascript function inside that of the master page?

Comment: Felix you need to check by put JavaScript function over there and if you get object that's it.

Comment: hi i got the control and its valu of the master page. But now I need to call another javascript function from my Iframe page...